# Getting NSmutableDictionary key from two mutable arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have three mutable arrays

```
@interface PickeriviewAndTableViewController ()
//Create mutableArray for tableView

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *msgYear;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *msgSeason;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *msgCourse;
```

I want to add element to array `msgCourse[ ]` using the key generating from the first two arrays `msgYear[ ]` and `msgSeason[ ]`.

Then I want to populate the msgCourse[] array using a button

```
- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {


    //To get value from pickerView, prepare for key and contents

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *num=Number[numRow];
    NSString *season=Season[SeaRow];
    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];

    NSString *CourseToAdd=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",course];
    NSString *SeasonToAdd=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",season];
    NSString *YearToAdd=[[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%@ ",num];

// Try to generate key from YearToAdd and SeasonToAdd and fill in content
   NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   NSString *keyFromYearAndSeason = @"Don't_know_what_to_do_here";
  [contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Don't_know_how", nil] forKey:keyFromYearAndSeason];

[keys addObject:keyFromYearAndSeason];

[self setSectionKeys:keys];
[self setSectionContents:contents];

}
```

My question is: How to complete my code by replacing these "Don't know how" lines of code here please?

Update: To be more clear, key is generating from `msgYear[ ]` and `msgSeason[ ]` e.g. '2001 fall', dictionary is filled with course e.g. 'chemistry','math'.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.  When you say "key from year and season" do you mean simply a concatenated string - e.g. "2014fall" ? And what are the objects that you want to put in the array in the dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, key is concatenated string - e.g. "2014 fall"(with space), in the dictionary, I want to put course e.g. the elements from the 3rd array.

Comment: For the key just concatenate the strings - `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",num,season]`  I don't see a course array - just a course string.

Comment: And there is no need for a `keys` array - you can simply retrieve the keys from the NSDictionary - unless you want to maintain the order, then the array is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Sorry, I am not quite clear for my question, I ask this one because I got stuck in another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496839/populating-multiple-sections-tableview-using-pickerview/29496911#29496911

Comment: Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74667/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user4441082).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to your other question helped provide context for what you are trying to achieve.

You don't need to create a dictionary or an array inside the addButtton method - you should have your dictionary as a property that is already initialised.
Then, in add button you retrieve the array associated with the key - if the value is nil then you create a new array and put the course in. If the value isn't nil simply add the course to the array.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *tableEntries;  // alloc/init this in viewDidLoad


- (IBAction)addCourse:(UIButton *)sender {

    //To get value from pickerView, prepare for key and contents

    NSInteger numRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kNumComponent];//0=1st,1=2nd,etc
    NSInteger SeaRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kSeaComponent];//0=fall,1=spring,2=summer
    NSInteger CourseRow=[picker selectedRowInComponent:kCourseComponent];

    NSString *num=Number[numRow];
    NSString *season=Season[SeaRow];
    NSString *course=Course[CourseRow];

    NSString *key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",num,season];

    NSMutableArray *courses=self.tableEntries[key];
    if (courses == nil) {
        courses=[NSMutableArray new];
        self.tableEntries[key]=courses;
    }

    [courses addObject:course];

}
```

`NSDictionary`s are unordered, so you need to give some thought to how you want to order the data in your table.  You could use an array to hold the keys as in your original code and then sort this array.